# how to create dynamic multi-dimensional array of objects with in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects that has information about cars. I want to grouping on `categoryId`

```
var car = [
  { category: 1, model: "bmw" },
  { category: 1, model: "benz" },
  { category: 1, model: 'ford' }
  { category: 2, model: "kia" },
  { category: 2, model: "fiat" },
  { category: 3, model: "mg" },
];
```

I want this result

```
[  
  [
    { category: 1, model: 'bmw' },
    { category: 1, model: 'benz' },
    { category: 1, model: 'ford' }
  ],
  [ 
    { category: 2, model: 'kia' },
    { category: 2, model: 'fiat' }
  ],
  [ 
    { category: 3, model: 'mg' }
  ]
]
```

this is my solution but I want a way for this result based on reduce or ... I dont want to use `if` in `forEach`

```
let groupedCars = [];
cars.forEach((car) => {
  if (!groupedCars[car.category]) {
    groupedCars[car.category] = [];
  }
  groupedCars[car.category].push(car);
});
```

Comment: Your code is using arrow functions. Your code is using ES6.

Comment: I don't want use if in foreach

Comment: You can use ```for...of``` loop if you want ES6

Comment: forEach is still ES6 btw.

Comment: "*I want a way for this result based on reduce*" - why? What do you think is wrong with the current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method. Traverse the array and group it by category using reduce and at last, use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the result.

```js
const car = [
  { category: 1, model: 'bmw' },
  { category: 1, model: 'benz' },
  { category: 1, model: 'ford' },
  { category: 2, model: 'kia' },
  { category: 2, model: 'fiat' },
  { category: 3, model: 'mg' },
];

const ret = Object.values(
  car.reduce((prev, c) => {
    const p = prev;
    const key = c.category;
    p[key] = p[key] ?? [];
    p[key].push({ ...c });
    return p;
  }, {})
);
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you mean by ***result based on ES6***. But, you could try using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method.

**NOTE**: Javascript arrays start with index `0` so, you might need to add some logic in your code to fix that

Comment: yes I want to use reduce or like this... how can I use of reduce to gain this result?